# How to set transaction isolation level using classic ASP?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic, isolation-level

I have a `classic ASP` page and want to set the `transaction isolation level` to `READ UNCOMMITTED`. Using [this documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_conn_isolationlevel.asp) I have came up with the following:

```
Set conn = GetConnection
conn.IsolationLevel = adXactReadUncommitted

'conn.BeginTrans

'conn.CommitTrans

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[A] ([IsolationLevel]) SELECT CASE transaction_isolation_level  WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified'  WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncommitted'  WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted'  WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable'  WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable'  WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL  FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions  where session_id = @@SPID"
Set rs = cmd.Execute()

response.write(conn.IsolationLevel)
```

The last `response.write` gives me correctly `256` (`READ UNCOMMITTED`) but when I query the table I got only `ReadCommitted` records.

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

---

And here is the body of the `GetConnection` function:

```
FUNCTION GetConnection()
    DIM strConnectionDotNet : strConnectionDotNet = "Data Source=..."
    SET GetConnection = Server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    GetConnection.connectionstring="Provider=sqloledb;" & strConnectionDotNet
    GetConnection.open
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: Why not move all your sql to stored procedures? This would make this kind of thing a lot simpler. The bigger question I have is why are you trying to use read uncommitted from classic asp? That is typically for an OLTP system and that level of isolation is generally a bad idea for that because it can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows.

Comment: I am not able to wrap the code in `SQL object` easily as the `t-sql` statement is build dynamically in `classic asp` pages. For the given query to display such data (duplicated rows, phantom reads, etc) its ok.

Comment: That is a very slippery slope when you start building sql statements in code. It makes me shudder. You can achieve the same thing by adding the nolock hint to each table in your query. All too often I see people wanting to use uncommitted and then get confused when the results are inaccurate at random time.

Comment: The statement is very complicated. I need to add the `WITH (NOLOCK)` many times and in many functions. This is legacy code - I do not like it, but    I need to handle it now. Do not worry about the uncommitted data - in this business case it makes perfect sense to use this isolation level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said in the documentation:

> Note: The IsolationLevel settings will not work until next time
>   BeginTrans is called.

It is a kind of strange, but I need to the following:

```
conn.BeginTrans
... sql statement is executed here
conn.CommitTrans
```

Even thought the `T-SQL` statement is a `SELECT`. Also, after the `conn.CommitTrans` it is still using the default isolation level (the one specified in the context of the database).